# Inject Dependency to Utility Class Map

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, utility-method

I have a utility/constants class that contains a `Map<String, Authorizer>` where `Authorizer` is an interface with a few different implementations.  I use the map across different streams to take in an object that contains some `String` (the name of an Authorization approach) that then maps to a specific `Authorizer`, which then completes some authorization.

I am using Guice to wire the `Authorizer` classes, but this approach prevents me from making the utility class (which contains the `Map`) a true utility class with an empty private constructor.  I have a funky-looking workaround that pleases both Guice and Checkstyle, but I want to know if there is a better way.

My Utility Class:

```java
public final class Constants {
  @Inject
  private Constants() {}

  public static final String AUTH_METHOD_ONE = "Auth1";
  public static final String AUTH_METHOD_TWO = "Auth2";

  @Singleton
  @Inject
  @Getter // For Checkstyle, as AUTH_METHODS isn't a true static final constant
  private static Map<String, Authorizer> authMethods;
}
```

My Constants Module:

```java
public class ConstantsModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    requestStaticInjection(Constants.class);
    final MapBinder<String, Authorizer> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, Authenticator.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding(AUTH_METHOD_ONE).to(MethodOneAuthorizer.class);
    mapBinder.addBinding(AUTH_METHOD_TWO).to(MethodTwoAuthorizer.class);
  }
}
```

And an example usage:

```java
public class AuthorizationOrchestrator {
  private static Authorizer getAuthorizer(final AuthorizationState state) {
    return state.getMethods().stream()
      .map(AuthorizationApproach::getAuthorizationApproachName)
      .filter(Constants.getAuthMethods().keySet()::contains)
      .findFirst()
      .map(Constants.getAuthMethods()::get)
      .orElse(null);
  }
}
```

This approach also requires some PowerMock usage in the Unit Tests.  Is there a better way to:

- Map the names of the authorization approaches to an `Authorizer` class while keeping the mapping in one place?
- Use the `Constants` class as a true utility class with `public static final Map<String, Authorizer> AUTH_METHODS` while still being able to inject the authorizers into the `Map`?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t really make sense to inject something that is supposed to be a constant.

By using a static `Constants` class, you are introducing a non-injected dependency into the code that uses your `Constants` class, which goes against the whole point of DI—not to mention that static dependencies are more difficult to mock in your tests.

There’s a few other ways to do this that might work for you. In principle,  they’re all the same solution (inject the `Authorizer`s into something that is not static), but they have a few different nuances.

- **Use composition to avoid needing a utility class.** Make an `Authorizer` implementation that is composed of multiple `Authorizer`s. The composite `Authorizer` could internally delegate to the correct “real” implementation. Then you can just inject a single `Authorizer` anywhere that needs one. This on might not be possible depending on how the `Authorizer` contract is defined.
- **Keep the logic without any state in the utility class.** Change the signature of the static method to`getAuthorizer(AuthorizationState state, Map<String, Authorizer> availableAuthorizersByName)`.  Then, inject the `AUTH_METHODS` map directly into the classes that would be calling your static `getAuthorizer` method, and pass the map as one of the arguments to the method.
- **Make `getAuthorizer()` not static.** And inject the map directly into an instance of`AuthorizationOrchestrator`.